# Type powers of ten using a custom command

Tags: macros, superscripts

I use the font `times` and I am writing powers of ten often. So I am using `10\textsuperscript{2}`. I was wondering if it is possible to make a command like `\ten{2}` which does the same thing? It would make it faster for me to type and is also very clear to read in my editor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
10\textsuperscript{2}
%\ten{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `times` is deprecated and ought not be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ten}[1]{10\textsuperscript{#1}}
\usepackage{blindtext,times}
\begin{document}
    \ten{2}\blindtext\par\ten{324}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please could you edit your code to make it compilable?

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps a more versatile solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \num{e2}

    \num{1e5}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Would not be very clear for the editor reading it, though. Also, doesn't this give you a bad box warning?

Comment: @cfr Do you mean the code or the output not being clear for the editor? I don't quite understand: if you mean editor (of a journal, say) or the TeX editor, or..? And no, it doesn't. It does for you?

Comment: I thought part of the point was to make the source more readable for the editor. That's what the question said was part of the motivation for `\ten{#1}`. And I didn't check yet. Shouldn't it give a bad box warning, though?

Comment: @cfr oh ok, so the editor as mentioned in the question, i.e., the TeX editor. Whether it's more readable seems to be in the eye of the beholder IMO. I don't find this any harder to read than `\ten{2}`, say. But it's more versatile, and has the benefit of being a more well-known command. In either case, it's better than `\textsuperscript` which is the main problem posed by OP. With regards to bad box, I don't know.. It doesn't for me. You mean the bad box to come from using `\\\`?

Comment: I agree it is more versatile. And, yes, shouldn't that give a bad box warning? Now I can't produce a bad box warning using `\\ ` at all. (I.e. no matter how hard I try.]

Comment: @cfr I do know that it's not good practice though -- I don't do this in my own documents. I'll just change it anyway :)

Comment: You need another `\noindent` or drop the one you've got.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `knitr`, just write a `\Sexpr{}`:

```
<<echo=F>>=
options(scipen=-3)
@
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\Sexpr{10^2} \Sexpr{10^5} \Sexpr{10000} \Sexpr{100} \Sexpr{0.0000123}
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]